# asp.net - Developing web application with features enabled based on configuration

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I need to develop a web based product. Features of this will be available to users based on subscription categories like Basic Version /Premium Version / Enterprise Version. I would like to maintain single source for these subscription categories.

Here my question is,

How to design web application, which has features enabled based on configuration / subscription categories?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This is very general question, and I will answer generally.

You can assign Roles to your registered users, and then you check using the `IsUserInRole` to 
see what you going to show and what not.

To gain speed you can assign the permission to the user session and not always call the `IsUserInRole`

You can open and close some part of your page using the `Panel` and the Visible of it. Also close the Viewstate of the Panels that are hidden.

Alternative you can use `UserControls` that inside of them you check if the user have permission to see it or not, and you hide it OnInit, and also disable the ViewState of it.

And of course if a full page is not permitted you can always make a full redirect.

So **a full page** can have `Panels`, and `UserControls`, and the views of it depend from the user level.

Comment: Thanks...

If i loaded more controls on single page and enabling / disabling based on configuration on DB, will it 
effect performance on this page and how to handle this? beacuse my users are mostly working on these core pages only.

Comment: @er.g.ilango I do not know if its real affect the performance, this is something that you need to check and avoid some thinks, or use some other way to load or not. The issue on this thinks is not to enable it or not, but I tell you this is very general question. You need to make some tests, how many controls ? how are you going to render them, what they do... This is how you design it. The performance have issue on how you get data from the database, how you handle the session and how you render the page in general.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get this readymade , you have to design the application based on the technology you are using.

I had similar kind of project going on in which we store the list of feature in database and when the page initializes loads the feature list in session.

On various pages we are showing/hiding controls based on the feature availability.

Offcourse Single feature can also have category based on the User Roles that we can check  using FormAuthentication methods and change the page server side accordingly.

Let me know if you have any specific approach in mind and have question related with it.

Comment: Thanks...

I am also thinking on same approach as you mentioned...

But my constrain is, I have few core pages on this system. So, i have to incorporate most of the product 
features on this these page only.

If i loaded more controls on single page and enabling / disabling based on configuration on DB, will it 
effect performance on this page and how to handle this? beacuse my users are mostly working on these core pages only.

Comment: offcourse it is not good practice to load all data on one page and enable/disable based on the role/feature, although we have done that too. as the page contains are rendering from server side you can make sure that you should not process the data which you are not going to render thus it will not decrease the performance.